# How can I find out that JavaFX Image loading in background has failed?

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, background-process

Question in short:

How can I find out, that background loading of `image` has failed just before `imageView.setImage(image)` results in showing an empty picture although `image.isError==false` and `image.getException==null`?

Background:

In my simple JavaFX based photoviewer app I use a TableView() for showing a directory with jpg files. Whenever one selects an entry in the table the picture is loaded using javafx Image class and is shown using an ImageView.

I load the photos in background using `true` in the parameter of the Image-constructor.
Once a photo is loaded I keep it in a list ("Cache") for faster "showing again"

Here the code snippet:

```
public Object getMediaContent() {
Image image = (Image) content;

if (!isMediaContentValid()) {  //if not already loaded or image in cache is invalid
  try {
    System.out.println("getMediaContent loading " + fileOnDisk);
    content = new Image(fileOnDisk.toUri().toString(), true);  //true=load in Background
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //will not occur with backgroundLoading: image.getException will get the exception
    System.out.println("Exception while loading:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} else {
  System.out.println(fileOnDisk.toString() + "in Cache :-)...Error="+ image.isError() + " Exception=" + image.getException());
}
return content;
```

}

In `isMediaContentValid()` I test

- if the image is already in the cache's list
- and if `image.isError()` is `false`
- and if `image.getException(`) is `null`

The problem:

When the user selects photos very quickly (e.g. by using cursor down key) images are still loaded in background (for the cache) while the next photo's loading has already started.
My simple chache algorithm has problems to find out when I run out of memory because there might be enough memory when loading is started but not to complete all background tasks.

But I expected that this is not a problem because `image.isError()` would report `true` or `image.getException()` would be `!= null` in this case. So I could free memory before retrying.

But `isError()` reports `false`, `getException()` reports `null` and the image is shown "empty" in imageView :-(

The question:
How can I find out, that background loading of `image` has failed just before `imageView.setImage(image)`?

Comment: While the image is still loading, it has neither an error nor an exception. These are determined only when the image has finished loading or stopped loading because of an error. Why do you assume, then, that `isError` will tell you anything?

Comment: You are right. fabians answer adresses this perfectly. Thank you for help. Ingo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find out, that background loading of image has failed just before `imageView.setImage(image)`?

This is not possible. The whole point of loading the image in the background is that it's done asynchronously. There is no guarantee that the exception already occured at the time the method returns. You need to use a listener to the `error` property to be notified of a failure to load the image.

**Example**

```
Image image = new Image("https://stackoverflow.com/abc.jpg", true); // this image does not (currently) exist
image.errorProperty().addListener(o -> {
    System.err.println("Error Loading Image " + image.getUrl());
    image.getException().printStackTrace();
});
```

Comment: Thank you fabian. ...don't know why I had this idea earlier ;-) Simple and great! Ingo